# Refresh the page automatically in react native (Class Component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have an order screen and I am getting its data from API. Is there any way to refresh the screen automatically, because I can't get new data until I restart the app

Comment: May I know when you are about the refresh the screen data?

Comment: Are you really asking how to fetch data on an interval, aka, polling your backend API? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Jigneshmayani, When user click on button (Approve / Reject )

Comment: @SuhailKakar Check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try by **creating a re-usable method** for getting the updated data from the API and make calls to the API when onApprove or onReject Action occurs.

like :

```
loadData = async () => {
    /*
    *  Process your api call here...
    */
}

onApprove = async () => {
    /*
    *  Process your approve button press and then call the loadData again
    */
    await loadData()
}

onReject = async () => {
    /*
    *  Process your rejecgt button press and then call the loadData again
    */
    await loadData()
}
```

**Also, maintain the list refreshing functionality to show the loader** appropriately when data is loading.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this where you want to receive orders when new orders arrive without having a user to refresh screen. You need to implement **Socket** to achieve it.